# How to open SharePoint project folder links in Windows (OneDrive) File Explorer?

Tags: onedrive

I need to put buttons on SharePoint project web pages that will open SharePoint folders in new file explorer windows.

So when I click on a SharePoint web link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6PN0.png)

Thanks in advance.